# Why is this KMP code showing a runtime error?

Tags: algorithm, c++11, codeblocks

Is returning a vector from the function is creating any problem? or is it just some basic syntax problem?

It is  just the sample code from [CLRS](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs97si/10-string-algorithms.pdf). The computePrefix function computes values for proper prefix of the given pattern and matches the values in main function.

Getting a SIGSEGV error to be more precise. Your kind advice will really be helpful.

Thank you.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text, pattern;
    vector<int> computePrefixFunction(string p);
    cin >> text;
    cin >> pattern;
    int n = text.length();
    int m = pattern.length();
    vector<int> pi = computePrefixFunction(pattern); 
    int q = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        while(q > -1 && pattern[q+1] != text[i])
            q = pi[q];
        if(pattern[q+1] == text[i])
            q = q + 1;
        if(q == (m-1))
        {
            cout << "Pattern occurs from position: " << q - m + 1 << '\n';
            q = pi[q];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

vector<int> computePrefixFunction(string p)
{
    int m = p.length();
    vector<int> pi;
    pi[0] = -1;
    int k = -1;
    for(int q = 0; q < m; ++q)
    {
        while(k > -1 && p[k+1] != p[q])
            k = pi[k];
        if(p[k+1] == p[q])
            k = k + 1;
        pi[q] = k;
    }
    return pi;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a `vector`, do `push_back` to add elements to it. If you just initialize it without a size like you do on the second line of `computePrefixFunction`, trying to access `pi[0]` or `pi[q]` will give you a runtime error. Instead, do `pi.push_back(value)`.

Comment: Glad it helped @user3805080. Please upvote and/or accept the answer if it works for you.